# How to make an element disappear after the other is shown?

Tags: jquery

There are thee buttons that toggle classes of three different elements: the first button shows-hides the first element, the second shows-hides the second element and so on.

The problem is that when the next element appears, the previous does not go away. How to make it possible to have only one current element on a page after press a certain button?

Well, the goal is: I press the first button - the first element is shown, I press the second button and after that the first element goes away and the second element is shown.

```
$(function() {

    // show-hide content ONE
    $('.show-content-one').on('click', function(){
        $('#hidden-content-one').toggleClass('hidden-content-one-show');
    });
    $('.close-content-one').on('click', function(){
        $('#hidden-content-one').toggleClass('hidden-content-one-show');
    });

    // show-hide content TWO
    $('.show-content-two').on('click', function(){
        $('#hidden-content-two').toggleClass('hidden-content-two-show');
    });
    $('.close-content-two').on('click', function(){
        $('#hidden-content-two').toggleClass('hidden-content-two-show');
    });

    // show-hide content THREE
    $('.show-content-three').on('click', function(){
        $('#hidden-content-three').toggleClass('hidden-content-three-show');
    });
    $('.close-content-three').on('click', function(){
        $('#hidden-content-three').toggleClass('hidden-content-three-show');
    });

});
```

I've studied this example

http://blogs.html5andcss3.org/show-and-hide-multiple-div-using-javascript/,

but cannot use it in my case. I guess there should be something like a condition: if some element has (or has not) some class - then do this.

Here's my [example](https://codepen.io/rinatoptimus/pen/oWPwpa).

Comment: I'd just use .show(), then .hide() on the object itself

Comment: You would have to do your hide command for 2 and 3 if you show 1...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done very economically as follows :

**CSS**

Replace:

```css
#hidden-content-one,
#hidden-content-two,
#hidden-content-three {
    position: relative;
    height: 0;  
    overflow: hidden; 
}
.hidden-content-one-show,
.hidden-content-two-show,
.hidden-content-three-show {
    height: 100px !important; 
    padding: 10px;
}
```

with:

```css
.wrapper > div {
    position: relative;
    height: 100px; 
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
}
```

**Javascript**

Replace existing javascript with:

```js
$(function() {
    $('.block-btns button').on('click', function() {
        // toggle button's content, hide other content
        $('.wrapper > div').eq($(this).index()).toggle().siblings().hide();
    });
    $('.wrapper .close').on('click', function() {
        // hide active content
        $(this).closest('div').hide();
    });
});
```

**[Demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mmGpLr)**

This will accommodate any number of buttons/content.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple example using the index of the button that matches the index of the div that you want to display.

```js
(function($){$(function(){
  // start all hidden
  var divs = $('.container > div')
  divs.hide()
  
  $('.buttons button').on('click', function(event){
    // hide all
    divs.hide();
    
    // show the div that matches the button index
    divs.eq($(this).index()).show()
  })
})})(jQuery)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="buttons">
<button>show 1</button>
<button>show 2</button>
<button>show 3</button>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately if press a button again content is still visible.